# Python not implemented exception in python escpos pyusb, libusb, on chinese thermal printer 58mm Working in Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, libusb, escpos

So more than a question it's an answer. I got a 58mm receipt printer and i was trying to setup with escpos sdk's, so far so good i spent all day getting redundant errors like "not implemented" raise errors, and there are not so much information about it. So i'll post what i did in order to get it to work.

First, read first step of [this guide](https://python-escpos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and install all libraries from dependencies steps (i use anaconda to manage my virtual envs, so i installed via anaconda prompt)

Then, download libusb from [here](https://libusb.info/) from lastest windows binaries, unzip it and search for 32 or 64 bits dll's depending of your OS (apparently this is important in order to work) for 64 bits select MS64/dll files and copy it in windows/system32, for 32 bits MS32/dll files, in windows/SYSWOW64, folder path should be in your %PATH% variable inside windows configuration. If you are using anaconda and activate a virtual env, copy it inside "X:\USERS\USER\Anaconda3\envs\ENV\DLLs" and  "X:\USERS\USER\Anaconda3\envs\ENV\Library\bin" where x, user and env should match with your virtual environtment path folder, (if you installed anaconda for all users, user should be on "all users" folder, and it's hided for default)

Run this code in python and will prompt a list of all your devices vid's and pid's, and you need to pick printer vid and pid, if your need to google your pid's and vid's (just 4 digit number after) do it and investigate each one to find your printer id, and after you get those info store it somewhere. Note, if you do this after driver install, you may not see your printer listed there. In my case was VID_0483&PID_070B.

```
import win32com.client

wmi = win32com.client.GetObject ("winmgmts:")
for usb in wmi.InstancesOf ("Win32_USBHub"):
print(usb.DeviceID)
```

Get [Zadig](https://zadig.akeo.ie/) and install it, after installation open it and clic option menu, then list all devices, (YOU WON'T SEE ANY DEVICES IF YOU DON'T DO THIS) and then search for your device, mine was listed under "Usb printing support" select it, verify pid and vid vendor match with yours and then select WinUsb driver, then press install/reinstall button, should take a while to do it (be patiente).

At this point you should be done installing libraries and drivers, and you should run this code with no issues, and get something like this <usb.backend.libusb1._LibUSB object at 0x000001F74D7BD688>.

```
import usb.core
import usb.util
import usb.backend.libusb1
backend = usb.backend.libusb1.get_backend()
print(backend)
```

Here's the tricky part. If you run this code:

```
from escpos.printer import Usb
import usb.core
import usb.util
import usb.backend.libusb1

p = Usb(0x0483, 0x070B, 0, 0x81, 0x02)
p.text("Hello World            Hola   1\n")
```

You are typically going to get "not implemented" raise error, because escpos libraries are not written for windows! :/. So, back in your env folder, or python installation folder, go to ENV/lib/site-packages/escpos/ and open printer.py file. Comment from line 61 to 71 or delete it, but if you are new like me just type a # in each line. Should be in same column to avoid identation errors. Do it just below "check_driver = None" line, and above line 73, like this:

```
        check_driver = None

    #try:
    #    check_driver = self.device.is_kernel_driver_active(0)
    #except NotImplementedError:
    #    pass

    #if check_driver is None or check_driver:
    #    try:
    #        self.device.detach_kernel_driver(0)
    #    except usb.core.USBError as e:
    #        if check_driver is not None:
    #            print("Could not detatch kernel driver: {0}".format(str(e)))

    try:
        self.device.set_configuration()
        self.device.reset()
    except usb.core.USBError as e:
        print("Could not set configuration: {0}".format(str(e)))

def _raw(self, msg):
```

And then ou should be able to communicate with your printer. Run again:

```
from escpos.printer import Usb
import usb.core
import usb.util
import usb.backend.libusb1

#remember to change pid and vid with your own values!
p = Usb(0x0483, 0x070B, 0, 0x81, 0x02)
p.text("Hello World            Hola   1\n")
```

And you should see one line printer in your printer!, you may need to press paper feed button to see it. If you get invalid endpoint, you need to set your own endpoint in Usb() arguments function next to vid and pid, (0x81,0x02) and replace those. Usually are 0x81 and 0x82 but may vary.

I hope you find usefull this info, cheers!

Comment: Are you thinking too complicated? If you are using Windows, you can simply use the SerialPort instead of the low-level USB mechanism. Since it is not Android, you should be able to use SerialPort as it is.

Comment: Then what you call `escpos sdk` is a bunch of third party libraries, not a packaged SDK. For example, the official SDK is available from this site. [TM-T88VI](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=prod&pcat=3&pid=4983) Even a third-party library may be able to do what you want, but it will be difficult to get advice and answers.